# Access Another Class from a Dictionary within a Class

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I am trying to access class Castle() by using a dictionary within class Rooms().

I dont understand how to access just room1 or room2 without accidently accessing both?

I have exhausted every avenue I can think of but im sure its probably something very simple Im missing. Thanks in advance!

```
class Castle():
    def enter():
        print("This is castle")


class Door():
    def enter():
        print("This is door")


class Rooms():
    def dictionary():
        items = {
        'room1': Castle.enter(),
        'room2': Door.enter()
        }

Rooms.dictionary()['room1']
```

it prints out:

```
This is castle
This is door
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\James\Python\03_ZedShaw\test.py", line 22, in <module>
    Rooms.dictionary()['room1']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: You forgot to return `items` from `dictionary`. Also, `enter` methods do not return anything so everything in `items` will be `None` anyway. You may want to revisit how Python functions work

Comment: Also, `dictionary` is lacking an argument or the `@staticmethod` decorator. Anyway, why is `dictionary` not just a ... dictionary?

Comment: I am trying to create a game using classes for basically everything (which seems stupid to me but its apart of the exercise for Learn Python the Hard Way ex43). I assume its so I get used to understanding how inheritance works etc, but to be honest its just made everything super complicated. I tried adding return to enter methods and items but I get the same result. Ive been trying to fix this for 3 days lol... Ive lost all sense of whats going on

Comment: FWIW, the SO Python Chat room regulars [do not recommend LPTHW](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints). If it's working for you, that's great, but please be aware that there are several problems with this book.

Comment: You aren't using classes correctly. In fact, writing a game like this correctly is very, *very* difficult. It's a terrible exercise for beginners. You should probably find a better exercise to solve - and maybe find a proper OOP tutorial, as well.

Comment: lol you guys are not wrong, its definitely a crazy way to make a game! I made a few other games so far just using def methods and they worked well and were a joy to make. I have been working on this one for 2 weeks now and I feel like Im going to tear my hair out... lots of telltale signs this is not the way it should be done. From what I understand so far classes are great for instances, not really for individual methods

Comment: lol PM 2RING I seen your comment on the chat: How do you tell someone that almost everything that they think they know about classes is plain wrong? stackoverflow.com/questions/…I have to agree with you, it feels wrong in every way :D :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You forgot to return `items` from `dictionary`. Also, `enter` methods do not return anything so everything in `items` will be `None` anyway. You may want to revisit how Python functions work.
- It seems like a waste to recreate `items` every time `Rooms.dictionary` is called. You may use a class instance.
- As timgeb wrote in the comments, you forgot the `self` argument in methods, or the `@staticmethod` decorator.

```
class Castle:
    @staticmethod
    def enter():
        return "This is castle"


class Door:
    @staticmethod
    def enter():
        return "This is door"


class Rooms:
    items = {'room1': Castle.enter(),
             'room2': Door.enter()}

    @classmethod
    def dictionary(cls, key):
        return cls.items[key]

print(Rooms.dictionary('room1'))
# This is castle
print(Rooms.dictionary('room2'))
# This is door
```

At this point you don't actually need `Rooms.dictionary`:

```
class Rooms:
    items = {'room1': Castle.enter(),
             'room2': Door.enter()}


print(Rooms.items['room2'])
# This is door
```

Comment: thank you DeepSpace! this works, ill have to research what these classmethods and staticmethods are doing to make this work. Much appreciated!

Comment: Nothing in this answer is *wrong*, but it certainly isn't proper application of OOP either. A class that only has a single static method shouldn't be a class. The 3 bullet points are useful information, but the code by itself is downvote-worthy.

Comment: haha, yes Aran-Fey its stripped right down to make it easy to debug (just wanted to know how to use the dictionary to directly access a method within a class). But yes i think ill remove the classes for the rest of this exercise, please dont downvote me :D

Answer (score -2):

You should make the function return the dictionary first

```
return items
```

After that the dictionary need changes:

```
items = {
         'room1': 'Castle.enter()',
         'room2': 'Door.enter()'
        }
```

Then you need to use the `exec()` function if you don't expect output or `eval()` if you expect output like this:

```
exec(Rooms.dictionary()['room1'])
```

Comment: No, you don't need to use either `exec` or `eval` here